# Is it possible to extract an object with the properties of the master class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a class A and is inherited B.
Suppose class A has the following properties:

- propertyA1
- propertyA2
- propertyA3

Something like:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int propertyA1 { get; set; }
    public int propertyA2 { get; set; }
    public int propertyA3 { get; set; }
}
```

So our class B would have the following property:

- propertyA1 - Inherit A
- propertyA2 - Inherit A
- propertyA3 - Inherit A
- propertyB1 - Own B
- propertyB2 - Own B

Something like:

```
public class ObjectB : ObjectA
{
    public int propertyB1 { get; set; }
    public int propertyB2 { get; set; }
}
```

We create a new object of class B and imagine we have a list of 20 objects of the same type.
*Imagine that the properties of class A are 200 and Class B 100 are also both correspond to a table in the database.*

So, wanting to keep our data from the list of objects of class B (using **EntityFramework**), we want to save the information of class A in Table A.
Normally we would do the following:

```
foreach(var item in ObjectsB)
{
    ObjectA a = new ();
    a.propertyA1 = item.propertyA1;
    ...
    // And so on to put all the corresponding properties.
    db.TableA.add(a);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is where my question is:
Is it possible to create an object of class A from the object of class B? That is, omitting all the properties of the class B.
Something like:

```
ObjectA a = b.GetPropertiesFromMasterClass();
```

If so, we would avoid that assign the 200 propierties 
If possible, what is the way forward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
var b = new ObjectB();
var a = b as ObjectA;
```

More compact version:

```
ObjectA a = new ObjectB();
```

Comment: Very simple and quite functional! Thanks, works great!

Comment: This is casting and going to slow down the program. I have posted the complete example below.

Comment: I seriously doubt that micro-optimizations like this matter. Especially when dealing with databases (which are already magnitudes slower than this code) , where you have many many many more potential and real bottle necks to worry about.

Comment: @Avneesh Your claim is ridiculous. First, the cast is a simple reference conversion so it can't get any cheaper and second, you are dealing with DB latency here, what do a few more nanoseconds matter?

Comment: So you are telling that cast is better than direct assignment? You can keep adding few nano seconds every where you feel like in your program then. I am done with this question.

Comment: @Avneesh: There is no *cast*, it is a simple and obviously *valid* reference conversion which is equivalent to a direct assignment `ObjectA a = b`. The `as` is optimized away here because `b` will *always* be assignable to an `ObjectA`. The compiler *knows* this will succeed *always*. One of the worst decisions ever made in OO languages is placing completely different features in the *cast* bag; type conversions, reference conversions, boxing, etc.  The costs and implications of each one are radically diferent.

Answer (score 3):

Try Automapper:

`Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectA, ObjectB>();`

More details ca be found [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflection to assign the 200 properties in a `foreach` loop:

```
public class ObjectB : ObjectA
{
    public int propertyB1 { get; set; }
    public int propertyB2 { get; set; }
    // ...

    public ObjectA CreateA()
    {
        Type type = typeof(ObjectA);
        ObjectA result = new ObjectA();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {
                object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your solution involves unnecessary reflection (which is slow) together with creating an object 200 times as well, I don't see how you can see a problem in my answer to be honest with you

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making an update-able view in the database?  Then you could just update the view using Entity Framework syntax and be done.

Answer (score -1):

Using inheritance, you can create instances of B against A. Following example shows the object list:

```
 class A
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public string Property100 { get; set; }

        public string Property200 { get; set; }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public string PropertyB_1 { get; set; }
        public string PropertyB_2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> list = new List<A>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                A a = new B()
                {
                    Property1 = "P1_" + i,
                    Property2 = "P2_" + i,
                    Property100 = "P100_" + i,
                    Property200 = "P200_" + i,
                    PropertyB_1 = "PB_1_" + i,
                    PropertyB_2 = "PB_2_" + i
                };
                list.Add(a);
            }
            //list only contains A data
            foreach (A a in list)
            {
                //save a to database
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like to know what is wrong with the answer that a -ve is assigned?? No point just putting -ve to justify wrong assumptions about memory etc. Work on a good project that requires efficient memory coding.